# Duplicate Dates in Column Grouped using Group By

Tags: sql, group-by, duplicates, zoho

I am trying to gate the count of rows having same date from multiple tables using group by, But the resultant rows showing duplicate dates. I have changed date format to show only the date removing time from the date column.

```
SELECT
 userprofiles."date",
 COUNT(userprofiles."date") AS NumberofRegistration,
 COUNT(CallScheduleTableFB."Date") AS NumberofCalls
FROM  userprofiles LEFT JOIN CallScheduleTableFB ON userprofiles."date"  = CallScheduleTableFB."Date"  
GROUP BY  userprofiles."date" 
UNION
SELECT
 CallScheduleTableFB."Date",
 COUNT(userprofiles."date") AS NumberofRegistration,
 COUNT(CallScheduleTableFB."Date") AS NumberofCalls
FROM  userprofiles RIGHT JOIN CallScheduleTableFB ON userprofiles."date"  = CallScheduleTableFB."Date"  
GROUP BY  CallScheduleTableFB."Date"
```

EDIT
Following is output

```
userprofiles.date |NumberofRegistration |NumberofCalls
27/07/2016 |1 |0
28/07/2016 |0 |1
28/07/2016 |0 |1
28/07/2016 |0 |1
28/07/2016 |0 |1
30/07/2016 |0 |1
30/07/2016 |0 |1
03/08/2016 |1 |0
03/08/2016 |1 |0
03/08/2016 |0 |1
03/08/2016 |0 |1
```

Comment: Can You provide output data?

Comment: you should use subquery, put all your code into subquery and then group it again.

Comment: Thats because of the UNION operator. Anyway why do you have 2 COUNT()s?

Comment: I want count of both

Comment: @Tedo G. Can you please help me out with your suggestion

Comment: @SagarGalande, See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sagar Galande, This is my suggested code:

```
SELECT
      A.[Date]
    , SUM(A.NumberofRegistration) AS NumberofRegistration
    , SUM(A.NumberofCalls) AS NumberofRegistration
FROM
    (
    SELECT
         userprofiles."date" AS [Date],
         COUNT(userprofiles."date") AS NumberofRegistration,
         COUNT(CallScheduleTableFB."Date") AS NumberofCalls
    FROM  
        userprofiles 
            LEFT JOIN 
        CallScheduleTableFB 
            ON userprofiles."date"  = CallScheduleTableFB."Date"  
    GROUP BY  
        userprofiles."date" 
    UNION
    SELECT
         CallScheduleTableFB."Date" AS [Date],
         COUNT(userprofiles."date") AS NumberofRegistration,
         COUNT(CallScheduleTableFB."Date") AS NumberofCalls
    FROM  
        userprofiles 
            RIGHT JOIN 
        CallScheduleTableFB 
            ON userprofiles."date"  = CallScheduleTableFB."Date"  
    GROUP BY  
        CallScheduleTableFB."Date"
    ) AS A
GROUP BY
    A.[Date]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tedo G. for the answer. A perfectly fine working solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, since you want to count the values in both tables you need a `FULL OUTER JOIN` of the single `COUNTS`.

Like so:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(A.date, B.Date),
    COALESCE(A.NumberofRegistration, 0),
    COALESCE(B.NumberofCalls, 0)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
        userprofiles."date",
        COUNT(userprofiles."date") AS NumberofRegistration
        FROM  userprofiles
        GROUP BY  userprofiles."date" 
    ) AS A
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
        CallScheduleTableFB."Date",
        COUNT(CallScheduleTableFB."Date") AS NumberofCalls
        FROM  CallScheduleTableFB
        GROUP BY  CallScheduleTableFB."Date"
    ) AS B
    ON A.date = B.Date
```

`COALESCE` just returns the first non-NULL value of the ones provided.

Comment: Found a mistake in my query. Now it should work. Let me know! :)

Comment: I wanted to accept both the solutions but it is not allowed.